# Atom method suggestions using python

Tags: python, atom-editor

I just want atom to give me suggestions after "." and using method
But it shows them after typing first letters. I'm beginner and need that.
Something like VS code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What package(s) are you using for suggestions? I'm using `autocomplete-python` and it works like you want. For example, after typing `dict.`, it suggests `clear`, `copy`, etc.